# jqplot won't load after going to other page and going back to page with jqplot

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I've just started using [jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com/) for my page. And i was able to implement it and 
display a graph with data from my api.
At first, when I go to my page with `jqplot`, the graph will be displayed. But when I go to other page, then go back to that page, the grid then won't display.
In my console, it says:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

It was pointing to something like `var canvas = $.jqplot.CanvasManager.canvases[idx];`

`$.jqplot.CanvasManager` is undefined

Im not really familiar of jqpot yet.

Comment: Maybe it's an issue about order of dependencies loading... Did you initialize your graph once the DOM is ready ?

Comment: Did you initialize your graph once the DOM is ready ? 
Yes. But why does it display at first and then after going back to the page canvasManager becomes undefined?
But currently i'm looking it to providing the height and width. I probably miss it somewhere

Comment: I finally found my problem. I called destroy() before the plot existed